# Creating a Fragment in a Popup Window - in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, popupwindow, android-fragmentactivity

Is it possible to load a Fragment / FragmentActivity class on a PopupWindow? I need a PopupWindow with more than one site. On the first one should be some Buttons. With these Buttons you'll change the Layout of the Popup- and open a new one with, for example, some TextViews.

Comment: Check out the similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044593/properly-creating-a-fragment-in-a-popupwindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) Class. See this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html).